# CSS/SCSS position: absolute tooltip - prevent getting out of screen

Tags: css, sass

I have a tooltip made with position: absolute and pseudo elements. The problem is that when the element associated with the tooltip is too close to the side - the tooltip partly gets out of the screen and is unreadable. Is there a way I can calculate/prevent the tooltip going out of the screen?

http://jsfiddle.net/o9s4dy0t/25/

This is the CSS code:

```
.tooltip {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}



.tooltip:after {
    background: #111;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-radius: .5em;
    bottom: 1.35em;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(title);
    display: table;
    padding: .3em 1em;
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
    max-width:200px;
    right:60px;
    z-index: 98;
}

.tooltip:before {
    border: solid;
    border-color: #111 transparent;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8) transparent;
    border-width: .4em .4em 0 .4em;
    bottom: 1em;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

It's fine if the arrow is off - I might remove it in the future.

Comment: Show us HTML code too.

Comment: It's in the fiddle

Comment: Post it **in your question**. Linking to external resources is not recommended on StackOverflow.

Comment: If you're not using bootstrap you need to detect screen edges with javascript. CSS alone can't to that.

Answer (score -1):

This needs calculation to be done. Using plain CSS I don't think it will be possible. However, there are various libraries already doing so. One of the many is:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/
 You may use this in your code and make it work.

Comment: "Just use a library" is not a real answer.

Comment: @Turnip Well that was a suggestion. Going with library is not a compulsion. To my knowledge I don't think he/she will be able to do it using CSS only. and if something is already available on internet then rewriting the code again, I don't find it reasonable. But again that's my choice of working..accepting my choice is not necessary!